# Jquery Event Handlers for Accordions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events

I'm using a jQuery accordion and would like to save the existing click event for each accordion item, remove all the events, and add them back in when needed.  I'm familar with attaching/detaching handlers using .on and .off, but how do I go about preserving the default handler for each of the accordion items without overriding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery stores events and their handlers in `data('events`)` with each element. You can try something like this.

```
var oldHandlers = $('#datepicker').data('events');

$('elementSelector').unbind();//will unbind all the handlers
```

`oldHandlers` will be an object in this format.

```
{
   click: [ { 
              handler: function(){.. }
              ..
            }, 
            { 
              handler: function(){.. }
              ..
            }
            ..
           ]
   focus: [ { 
              handler: function(){.. }
              ..
            }, 
            { 
              handler: function(){.. }
              ..
            }
            ..
           ]
}
```

If you want to get the `click` handler from oldHandlers you can say.

```
if(oldHandlers && oldHandlers.click && oldHandlers.click.length > 0){
    $('elementSelector').click(oldHandlers.click[0].handler);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shankar, i'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
});

// will remove click event
$('#foo').unbind('click');
```

Comment: Mgraph, thanks, I do realize how binding a new click event works, i meant how to get at the existing out of the box default event in accordion, without overwriting it and recoding the default functionality.